# JQuery, how to trigger different drop event depending on which draggable

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

sorry if this question has already been answered but I have been looking for 2 days.
I have multiple draggable elements and one droppable and would like to call a different drop event based on which draggable was dropped.
Thanks.

```
$(function() {
$(".u").draggable();
$(".s").draggable();
$(".t").draggable();
$(".du").draggable();
$(".ds").draggable();
$(".dt").draggable();
$(".d").draggable();
$(".c").draggable();
$(".b").draggable();
$(".dd").draggable();
$(".ds").draggable();
$(".db").draggable();
$(".site").droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        switch (ui.draggable.attr('class')) {
            case "u":
                $(this).addClass("au");
                break;
            case "s":
                $(this).addClass("as");
                break;
            case "t":
                $(this).addClass("at");
                break;
            case "ds":
                $(this).addClass("ads");
                break;
            case "dt":
                $(this).addClass("adt");
                break;
            case "d":
                $(this).addClass("ad");
                break;
            case "c":
                $(this).addClass("ac");
                break;
            case "b":
                $(this).addClass("ab");
                break;
            case "dd":
                $(this).addClass("add");
                break;
            case "dc":
                $(this).addClass("adc");
                break;
            case "db":
                $(this).addClass("adb");
                break;
            case "du":
                $(this).addClass("adu");
                break;
        }
    }
})
});
```

nothing happens for any of them at the moment.

Comment: can you copy-paste your code to see how you've tried to do that?

Comment: Maybe show us what you tried and the result you are getting, then explain how you want it to work.

Comment: There, I have included my code, nothing currently happens when a draggable is dropped

Comment: the code is running on this website http://tbacode.ddns.net/quark.php

Comment: I added a default case and that is always run which suggests a problem with the switch..